# Eliminate accents of a string in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I would like to find a way to eliminate the accents of a string in postgresql.
For exemple, `'aaéeeà'` should become `'aaeeea'`.

any ideas ?

thank you for your answers, have a great day

best regards

Comment: You can [install](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createextension.html) the [unaccent](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/unaccent.html) extension and use the `unaccent()` function

Comment: both of your suggestions with ```unaccent()``` work for me, thank you for your asnwers, have a nice day!